# Reading binary markdown file on the client-side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, markdown, binaryfiles

I store markdown files in binary format in the mongoDB database using Binary() function. For example, data looks like this:

```
"IyBXZWVrQWhlYWQ6IDE4J05vdmVtYmVyIA0KDQojIyMgV29ybGQgZXZlbnRzDQoNClRoZSBuZXdzIGZsb3cgb24gVVMtQ2hpbmEgdHJhZGUgd2FyIGNvbnRpbnVlcyB0byBkcml2ZSBnbG9iYWwgbWFya2V0cy4gVGhlIFVTIHdpbGwgcHVibGlzaCB0aGU..."
```

How is it possible to convert it back on the client-side? I want to parse the md-file into HTML in the page. Can I convert it somehow? I tried FileReader: readAsText, readAsBinaryString, and readAsArrayBuffer and got an error "not type of Blob".

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: That is a base64 string not a file, hence why when passing that retrieved value to those methods you get the not a blob error. Use a base64 decode method, eg [`atob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob)

Comment: Oh, thank you. I will try to find a solution now!

Comment: @PatrickEvans, You are my hero! Could you provide it as an aswer below, so I will mark it as a correct answer? Thank you!